# Is this YouTube segment from the group known as "Anonymous"?

Tags: united-states, politics, quotes

Is this [YouTube segment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E5-TKWM4WCk), dated Dec 13, 2016 and titled "Anonymous to Trump", really a product of the group known as "Anonymous", or is it a spoof?

The segment gives a litany of the ways that Russia supposedly conspired against the US electoral system.

(I'll assume that further asking whether any of the claims are actually true is well beyond the scope of what "fits" in a single question here.)

Comment: Doesn't saying you're part of Anonymous make you part of it by definition?

Comment: @jwodder Pretty much.

Answer (score 21):

Anonymous has no leadership and isn't really a formalized group.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_(group)):

> Membership is open to anyone who wishes to state they are a member of the collective

So, as with your question, ignoring whether any of the claims have any basis in fact, if a video claims to be from "Anonymous", it, by definition, is.